# File Downloaded From SharePoint Online using PowerShell is not Formatted Correctly

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-rest-api, file, download, oauth

When using Powershell to download a file from SharePoint Online, the file is not encoded or formatted properly.

With the below code, I am able to successfully authenticate to the site and download a file from SharePoint Online but the file appears to have a bunch of ancillary information from the site and not the actual data that it should have in the file after downloading it.

Also, using Postman I can connect to the SharePoint online site and download the file successfully and it is formatted correctly but when I perform this  from PowerShell, using `Invoke-RestMethod`, it appears to not format the file correctly after saving the file to local disk.

Do I need to add a parameter or change the encoding to correctly format the saved file or am I missing something in the header? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Note: I would rather not use PowerShell PNP or CSOM as I want a solution that doesn't rely on any downloaded plug-ins, DLLs or any other local code requirements. I am trying to make it work with a REST call using OAuth token access.

```
[BEGIN CODE]

$filename = 'test1File.pdf'
$directory = 'C:\temp\'
$path = $directory + $filename
$outfile = "C:\temp\$filename"


Function GetAccessToken() {

$appId = '[app id]'                 #This is the Client ID
$appSecret = '[App Secret Here]'     #This is the Client Secret
$principal = '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'             #This is the SharePoint Principal ID
$realm = '[Tenant ID Here]'                 #This is the Tenant Id
$targetHost = 'https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx'  #This is the SharePoint Site
$resource = "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com@[Tenant ID Here]"

$body = [ordered]@{
grant_type = 'client_credentials'
client_id = "$appId@$realm"
client_secret = $appSecret
resource = $resource
}

$accessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/$realm/tokens/OAuth/2"  
$global:Access_Token = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $accessTokenUrl -Body $body -Method Post

Write-Host "Token =" $global:Access_Token.Access_token

}

Function DownloadFile() {

$url = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxx/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/xxxxxx/Documents')/Files('$filename')/$value"
$headers = @{'Authorization' = "Bearer $access_token";'Content-Type'="application/json";'Accept'="application/json;odata=verbose"}
$DownloadFile = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get -OutFile $outfile -Verbose
}

GetAccessToken

$access_token = $global:Access_Token.Access_token

DownloadFile

#Clear-Host
Write-Host "File Downloaded Successfully!"

[END CODE]
```

Below is a Snippet of what the file looks like after downloading it:

```
*/test1File.pdf')/Versions"}},"CheckInComment":"","CheckOutType":2,"ContentTag":"{ECB1B9A7-6774-467F-9A06-C91020BE52DD},2,1","CustomizedPageStatus":0,"ETag":"\"{[ETag]},2\"","Exists":true,"IrmEnabled":false,"Length":"215","Level":1,"LinkingUri":null,"LinkingUrl":"","MajorVersion":1,"MinorVersion":0,"Name":"test1File.pdf","ServerRelativeUrl":"/sites/xxxx/Documents/test1File.pdf","TimeCreated":"2021-07-02T19:29:25Z","TimeLastModified":"2021-07-02T19:29:25Z","Title":null,"UIVersion":512,"UIVersionLabel":"1.0","UniqueId":"[Unique ID]"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION] instead of using /$value at the end of the URL use /OpenBinaryStream().

example:  [https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/MySite/Shared%20Documents/MyDocument.docx')/OpenBinaryStream()](https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(%27/sites/MySite/Shared%20Documents/MyDocument.docx%27)/OpenBinaryStream()).

Once I used /OpenBinaryStream() I was able to see the downloaded file correctly. The answer was found in the below article.

[Download file contents from SharePoint Online via REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283274/download-file-contents-from-sharepoint-online-via-rest?rq=1)